# How to pass PHP or JavaScript variables to Windows cmd.exe

Tags: php, javascript

I have a VBScript (.vbs) file on my Windows 7 machine. To run that *.vbs file , I have to execute it from cmd by passing arguments. Ex( *.vbs arg1 arg2 arg3).

I want to run this *.vbs file from PHP or JavaScript. But arguments should be through variables. Ex ($a=arg1; $b=arg2; $c=arg3;) and then use this variable to pass to that *.vbs. Ex(*.vbs $a $b $c). How to do it, from JavaScript or PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options with PHP. You could use exec() or system(). I would also recommend using escapeshellarg() prior to passing in any user inputted values.

Links:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php

Comment: By using exec(). The following statement is possibl:
exec('n.vbs arg1 arg2 arg3');
But, i want following statement to work:
$a=arg1;
$b=arg2;
$c=arg3;
exec( 'name.vbs $a $b $c');
that means i want variables to be passd to cmd.


Acually i hav vbscript that sends email. I shud open that file from cmd only. (double click does not work.) i shud pass command line arguments to that file to execute. So i hv to 1st open cmd and than type file name, id, subjct. than press enter.
I want that id , subject shuld be 1st specified as variables and than use tos variables to run that vbs file. Plz help

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're aware of this already, but on some Windows servers (read: all windows servers), unless you run the Apache service as an actual executable, it will not be allowed to directly interact with your desktop.

That being said, use exec(), or simply put your query in backticks, like this:

```
$query = `cmd.exe`;
```

Comment: i am using xampp localhost. and $query = `cmd.exe`; does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

1. `exec()` function and write the command in it.
2. Or enclose the cmd command you want to execute inside **``** (back tick) operator.

Example:

```
$cmd=`xyz.vb $a $b $c`
```

The $cms variable will have the output of the script.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$fname="C:/sendemail.vbs";
$id="vkvk1993@gmail.com";
$h="hi";
$s="hhhhhhhhhha";
$q="$fname $id $h $s";
if(exec($q));

echo "Done";

?>
```